# Where does bottom and right border come from in abcPdf

Tags: c#, html, abcpdf

Why I am getting border on bottom and right when rendering html using abcAdf.
PS I got professional license using (ABCpdf9-64.dll)

**My process is to create page:**

1. I use master / child layout template in mvc (works)
2. I point to this html using abcPdf to convert into pdf

**Html rendered**

When my html gets rendered (plain) format : each originating from its respective location.

```
<h1>Layout</h1>
<p>
    content
</p>
```

**C# code to render pdf**

My code is as follows:

```
        using (var pdf = new Doc())
        {
            pdf.HtmlOptions.Timeout = 600000;

            pdf.HtmlOptions.AddTags = true;
            pdf.Page = pdf.AddPage();

            var id = pdf.AddImageUrl(url, true, 1024, true);
            if (allowPaging)
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    if (!pdf.Chainable(id))
                    {
                        break;
                    }

                    pdf.Page = pdf.AddPage();
                    id = pdf.AddImageToChain(id);
                }

                for (int i = 1; i <= pdf.PageCount; i++)
                {
                    pdf.PageNumber = i;
                    pdf.Flatten();
                }

                ////reset back to page 1 so the pdf starts displaying there
                if (pdf.PageCount > 0)
                {
                    pdf.PageNumber = 1;
                }
            }

            return store(pdf);
        }
```

**Output**

My text/html gets rendered ok but I get borders that I have not asked for.

Rendered output:

[image]

Please note the hairline in bottom of the image.

Comment: What is `abcPdf.GetPdfDoc`? I cannot find any such call in the [official ABCpdf documentation](http://www.websupergoo.com/helppdfnet/).

Comment: @RossPresser I have updated my example by removing function that was applying license

Comment: Is that border actually in the PDF, or rendered by your viewer?

Comment: It does render when I am converting html to pdf (ie9)

Answer (score 1):

After hours of googling about setting margin in abcpdf, I found nothing and took it as a challenge to find it myself.
I tried experimenting with everything I found relevant in the abcpdf documentation and finally made a chart myself 
for setting the margins. I have successfully implemented this in many situations. Hope this helps others.

Here is a code snippet that shows how to set margins-

string html; // my html content that should be shown in the pdf page

```
            Doc pdf = new Doc();

            // adjust the default rotation and save
            double w = pdf.MediaBox.Width;
            double h = pdf.MediaBox.Height;
            double l = pdf.MediaBox.Left;
            double b = pdf.MediaBox.Bottom;

            // explicitly giving page size
            pdf.MediaBox.String = "A4";
            pdf.Transform.Rotate(90, l, b);
            pdf.Transform.Translate(w, 0);
            pdf.Rect.Width = h;
            pdf.Rect.Height = w;

            int theID1 = pdf.GetInfoInt(pdf.Root, "Pages");
            pdf.SetInfo(theID1, "/Rotate", "90");

            int theID;
            pdf.Rect.String = "17 55 823 423";
            theID = pdf.AddImageHtml(html.ToString()); //Writes the HTML image to PDF
```

Here is a picture that describes margin layout for some junk values. Here
20 suggests that your content starts 20 pixels away from left of your pdf page
770 suggests that your content ends 770 pixels away from left of your pdf page
75 suggests that your content starts 55 pixels above the bottom of your pdf page
600 suggests that your content ends 600 pixels above the bottom of your pdf page

[image: abcpdf margin chart by CoffeeSipper]

In your case you have to add

```
pdf.Rect.String = "20 75 770 600"; // giving junk values
```

right before

```
var id = pdf.AddImageUrl(url, true, 1024, true);
```

NOTE: In this example I explicitly set landscape mode instead of portrait mode. But orientation doesn't matter for setting 
margins.